# Creating a User-Control

Tags: javascript, xml, user-controls, genexus

Genexus Evo3

I'm trying to create a User Control using Atom; it has to create a table of X rows and Y columns based on user input, i created the UC and put it on a mock Web Panel on a fresh KB just for this, but when i open the web panel the Chrome console returns:

Uncaught ReferenceError: [UserControlName] is not defined

These are my codes:

```
////TestRender.js
function test($)
{
    this.show = function()
    {   var html = ''
        html += '<div class="grid">';
        html += '<table>';
        for (var i = 0; i < this.TableCreate.EjeX; i++) {
             html += '<tr></tr>'
             for (var j = 0; j < this.TableCreate.EjeY; i++) {
                html += '<td></td>'
             }
        }
        html += '</table>'
        html += '</div>'
        this.setHtml(html);
    }

    this.destroy = function()
    {
        // Add your cleanup code here. This method will be called when the control is destroyed.
    }

    this.GetGrid = function()
    {
     return this.Grid;
    }

    this.SetGrid = function(data)
    {
        this.Grid = data;
    }
}

////test_Properties.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Content xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Object id="test_tlc">
        <Group>
            <Name>General</Name>
            <Type>Main</Type>
            <Children>
                <Prop>

                  <Id>TableCreate</Id>

                  <Name>TableCreate</Name>

                  <Type>Custom</Type>

                  <CustomType> Artech.GeneXus.Common.CustomTypes.ControlAttVarReference, Artech.GeneXus.Common </CustomType>

                  <Metadata>

                    <Value name="FlagSetValueMethod">SetGrid</Value>

                    <Value name="FlagGetValueMethod">GetGrid</Value>

                    <Value name="FlagDataTypeFilter">SDTTest_tlc</Value>

                  </Metadata>

                </Prop>
            </Children>
        </Group>
    </Object>
</Content>

////test.control

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ControlDefinition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Id>ad325e28-203d-48da-a49f-6ef4266d235a</Id>
    <Name>test_tlc</Name>
    <Description>test_tlc</Description>
    <ObjClass>test_tlc</ObjClass>
    <Version>1.00.00</Version>
    <RuntimeRender>test_tlcRender.js</RuntimeRender>
    <PropertiesDefinition>test_tlcProperties.xml</PropertiesDefinition>
    <DesignRender>test_tlcRender.xsl</DesignRender>
    <GxResources>sdtTest_tlc.xpz</GxResources>
    <ShowMethod>show</ShowMethod>
    <ResizeSupported>false</ResizeSupported>
    <DataSourceAllowed>None</DataSourceAllowed>
    <CustomDataSources />
    <AutoGrowSupported>false</AutoGrowSupported>
    <IncludeInControlInfo>false</IncludeInControlInfo>
    <SupportFiles />
    <iOS_SupportFiles />
    <Android_SupportFiles />
    <BB_SupportFiles />
    <Platforms>
        <Platform>Web</Platform>
        <Platform>WebLayout</Platform>
    </Platforms>
    <ReferencedFiles>

    <File>style.css</File>

</ReferencedFiles>
    <iOS_ReferencedFiles />
    <Android_ReferencedFiles />
    <BB_ReferencedFiles />
    <Constructor>
        <Parameters />
        <Name>test_tlc</Name>
    </Constructor>
    <ControlType></ControlType>
    <Categories />
    <Events>
        <!-- <Event>EventName</Event> -->
    </Events>
    <Methods>
        <!-- <Method>
            <Name>MethodName</Name>
            <Signature>SetMode( myMode: Modes, text: Character)</Signature>
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter>Modes</Parameter>
                <Parameter>Character</Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </Method> -->
    </Methods>
    <Actions>
        <!-- Declare new variable
        <Action>
            <Order>0</Order>
            <ActionProperties>
                <Property>
                    <Key>
                        <string>Name</string>
                    </Key>
                    <Value>
                        <string>VariableName</string>
                    </Value>
                </Property>
                <Property>
                    <Key>
                        <string>ATTCUSTOMTYPE</string>
                    </Key>
                    <Value>
                        <string>Variable Type</string>
                    </Value>
                </Property>
            </ActionProperties>
            <Data />
            <ActionType>VarDeclaration</ActionType>
        </Action> -->
        <!-- Se control property
        <Action>
            <Order>1</Order>
            <ActionProperties>
                <Property>
                    <Key>
                        <string>PropertyName</string>
                    </Key>
                    <Value>
                        <string>&amp;MyVariable</string>
                    </Value>
                </Property>
            </ActionProperties>
            <Data />
            <ActionType>SetPropertyToControl</ActionType>
        </Action>
        -->
        <!-- Code Snippet
        <Action>
            <Order>2</Order>
            <ActionProperties />
            <Data>
                // Events from gpxJSBuffer
                Event Start
                    msg("Hello world!")
                EndEvent
            </Data>
            <ActionType>CodeSnippet</ActionType>
        </Action>
        -->
    </Actions>
    <IsPublic>true</IsPublic>
    <Android_IsScrollable>false</Android_IsScrollable>
</ControlDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do a "/install" after moving the UC to the corresponding directory of the gx installation.

Comment: Consider rewriting your answer in English...